# MYSQL / PHP Authorisation Script

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I'm designing a website (as an absolute beginner) and I've encountered an issue. You can easily log in with this script:

http://pastebin.com/0HZkQxXg

That script works fine, however, you can just as easily type in "addressofserver:homepage.html". How do I authorise the log in? Do I need to put a script on my index files to kick people off unless they've logged in first?

How would you do this?

Thank-you.

Comment: The functions you are using to connect to MySQL are now deprecated and are considered a security risk. Please use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: There are a lot of good tutorials on the subject on Google, this isn't really on topic for SO because it's too broad. But if you want to prevent unauthorized access, then yes, you'd have to check if they're authorized.

Comment: For Hugohabel: It's a mock website for myself and I alone to practice mysql and php on. So instead of assuming other people were going to be accessing it, why don't you ask next time. Quite frankly however, I deprecate your assumptions (which one can only assume (heh) that you make upon reading all the other newbie posts. Sad, sad muppet. :^)

For Jereminah: I'm aware, thank-you for suggesting so though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually be running the pages as `.php` not `.html` as you stated in your question.

You'll also needed to check if the user can/is allowed to access the said page. That means you check the session that you just set:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) || !$_SESSION['loggedIn']) { 
    die(header("Location: /loginpage.php")); 
}
?>
```

Also, on every page that you need to access any session variables, you **will** need to start the session with:

```
session_start();
```

That means on your login processing script as well (*<sup>the one you posted</sup>*).